# Mobile Menu Jquery to make non-menu items clickable close menu.

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, menu

I have a simple script toogle code that opens and closes Mobile responsive Menu.

My issue is when the menu is open i want to also be able to also click the area outside of the menu to close the menu. Any help would be great.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mobile-toggle").click(function(){
            $("#mobile-menu").animate({
            left: "0px",
            opacity:1.0
    }, 100); 
});
    $("#mobile-toggle2").click(function(){
            $("#mobile-menu").animate({
            left: "-200px",
            opacity:1.0
    }, 100); 
}); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below JQUERY extension with existing code:

```
$.fn.clickOutsideThisElement = function (callback) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var self = this;
      $(document).click(function (e) {
          if (!$(e.target).closest(self).length) {
              callback.call(self, e)
          }
      })
    });
};
```

And call the function like this :

```
$("#mobile-toggle").clickOutsideThisElement(function() {
   $("#mobile-menu").animate({
       left: "0px",
       opacity: 0
   }, 1000);
}).click(function() { //Click inside menu
   $("#mobile-menu").animate({
       left: "-200px",
       opacity: 1.0
   }, 1000);
});
```

**[DEMO HERE >>](http://jsfiddle.net/68pcw/)**